# Record related error in Typescript. Why does it happen?

Tags: typescript

I'm getting an error about the Record value in Typescript, but I don't quite understand why. Is it because of extends? The code and error are below.

`error: 'null' is not assignable to type 'T[U]'`

```
const makeValuesNull = <T extends Record<string, any>, U extends keyof T>(object: T): T => {
  (Object.keys(object) as U[]).forEach((key) => object[key] = null); // object[key] >>>type error???
  console.log(object['123']);
  return object; 
};
```

Comment: object[key] = null
Here, all assignments, even if not null, are an error.

Comment: Works fine for me, given the TSConfig I have

Answer (score 1):

Since `version 3.9.5`, TypeScript enforces `strictNullChecks` on numbers and strings. So you have two options:

You can set `strictNullChecks` to false in `tsconfig.json`.

Or you can cast `null` to any to fix the problem:

```
const makeValuesNull = <T extends Record<string, any>, U extends keyof T>(object: T): T => {
  (Object.keys(object) as U[]).forEach((key) => object[key] = null as any);
  console.log(object['123']);
  return object; 
};
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwNYFMBqCA2BXFEBy2mmMAvDADwAqMKAHlCmACYQwBKKoATsxdNwCWYAOYAaGAjABPAHwSAqrQZNWMVNJAAzGFVkAKEACMAVlygAuXQEorNUrJgBvAFAwY%20gPKnzAOg0Qhj7AUNaSbAoA2gC61r5aINwAogjAABb6%20hphDjDGZiGRGtFkMGBEJAhsUtLWANwwAPSNecFQRSjSJbI9UNIADii03NyJAPwTbjCgkCCYKL6YICJBBe0A5ACMAEwAzOuxdVPcKFDY3GCtaw0uAL5HQA)

Comment: Alireza Ahmadi, thank you. I tested against strictNullChecks , and found that it has something to do with it. However, it is still not fully understood. Perhaps because of assuming that (object: T) can't have type U as user.find can't have a result, as described in this link (https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks)? Anyway, it helped a lot. Thank you.